# Get jekyll subcategory posts from collections

Tags: jekyll, config, blogs, posts

I have a subcategories for my collection posts, but I have a problem with loop, I need to get only one specific subcategory.

config.yml

```
collections:
  news:
    output: true
  cat1:
    output: true
    permalink: /news/cat1/:title/
  cat2:
    output: true
    permalink: /news/cat2/:title/
  cat3:
    output: true
    permalink: /news/cat3/:title/
  cat4:
    output: true
    permalink: /news/cat4/:title/
```

and this is the html file

```
---
# this is an empty front matter
title: 'Cat 1 news'
permalink: /news/cat1/
---

{% for item in site.news %}
  {% for post in item.cat1 %}
    {{ post.title }}<br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

there's my directory tree for this

```
_news
|  cat1
|  cat2
|  cat3
|  cat4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
{% for post in site.cat1 %}
```

or

```
{% assign myCategory = "cat1" %}
{% for post in site[mycategory] %}
```

Comment: Im already tried that, but It doesnt work. I added a directory tree in my post